# Django: How to nicely format an address in a template without knowing how much information is available?

Tags: python, django, formatting, django-templates, street-address

I have a table with address information. It has these fields.

- address_1
- address_2
- city
- state
- zip

No field is required. I want to display this in a template and format it nicely. I want line breaks between address_1, address_2, and the city/state/zip line for any of those that exists. I also want a comma between city and state if both exist. What is the best way to accomplish this? I started writing an if statement in the template, but it seemed to be getting a bit unwieldy. The big problem is that the user could enter only a city and state, only a zip code, a full-formed address, or anything between.

Comment: Do it in the handler, not the template. It'll be easier with the full expressiveness of python available

Comment: @RobCowie I had thought about this too. I seem to remember in the past having some trouble getting HTML from the handler to the template. Any suggestions on how to implement this? UPDATE: Just saw the other answer below. This is probably what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many ways of achieving this, none are likely to be that elegant. I'll throw this into the ring... Do this in your handler, and pass `address_parts` to the template context.

```
## Gather the address components in groups, removing any that are None
address_parts = filter(None, [
    model_obj.address_1,
    model_obj.address_2,
    u', '.join(filter(None, [model_obj.address_city, model_obj.state])),
    model_obj.zip,
])


## In the template, join the address groups
{{ address_parts|join:"<br>" }}
```

Comment: Very nice. This is far better than what I was attempting. Thank you!

Comment: This is really very elegant. I learnt 2 new things from your 1 answer which I know can be applied to many parts of my project. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you add a simple [custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-template-tags/) to append text to variables if they exist:

```
@register.filter
def append(arg, suffix):
    return arg + suffix if arg else ''
```

then you can do something like

```
{{ address_1|append:"<br/>" }}
{{ address_2|append:"<br/>" }}
{{ city|append:", " }}{{ state|append:" " }}{{ zip }}
```

If you want to do this in a `<table>` or whatever, you can also use a similar `prepend` filter.

Comment: This is interesting, but I believe it will always append those tags or characters, correct? I only want to append the breaks, for example, if an address element follows the one being appended to.

Comment: @raddevon This approach uses slightly different logic than you're thinking about but results in basically the same thing: if they give `address_1`, then there'll always be a `<br>` after it, but then the next actually present element is next. Two weird things: it'll end in a `<br>` if there's no `city`, `state`, or `zip` but not if there is, and if they give `city` but no `state` there'll be a stray comma after `city`. RobCowie's approach doesn't have these problems but also makes it harder to do custom formatting for each part (if you want to bold states, that'd need to go in the view).

Comment: You also need to make sure that your text is "safe". Otherwise the <br /> will be displayed as such.